# Finding dual cone for a set of copositive matrices

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, dual-cone, copositivity

This is a question from the textbook Convex Optimization by Stephen Boyd and Lieven Vandenberghe (2.35). I did read through the solution manual but I couldn't figure out why it is written the way it is and I wish if I could get some helps from this community.

---

> Given a matrix $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{S}^n$ is copositive, i.e. $\mathbf{z^TXz} \geq 0,  \mathbf{z} \succeq0$, also given the fact that the set of copositive matrices is a proper cone. Find the dual cone.

---

My solution is as follows:

Suppose $K$ is the set of copositive matrices in $\mathbb{S}^n$, $K = \{\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{S}^n : \mathbf{z^TXz} \geq 0, \forall \mathbf{z} \succeq 0\}$. $K^*$ is a set of normal vectors of all halfspaces containing K, defining as $K^* = \{\mathbf{Y}:\mathrm{tr}\mathbf{(Y^TX)}, \forall \mathbf{X} \in K \}$.

We know the equality that $\mathbf{z^TXz} = \mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{X^Tzz^T})=\langle \mathbf{X,zz^T} \rangle \geq 0$, so let $\mathbf{Y = zz^T}$.
\begin{align*}
K^* &= \{\mathbf{Y}: \mathbf{\langle \mathbf{X,Y}  \rangle}\geq 0, \forall \mathbf{X} \in K\} \\
&=\{ {\mathbf{zz^T}}: \mathbf{\langle \mathbf{X,zz^T}\rangle}\geq 0\ ,\forall \mathbf{X} \in K\} \quad \text{(Need to get rid of $\mathbf{X}$ from this expression)}\\
&=\{{\mathbf{zz^T}}:\mathbf{z} \succeq 0\} \quad \text{(as $K$ is pointed and non-empty, and $\mathbf{X} \in K$)}
\end{align*}

But according to the solution manual, it is the actually convex hull of the set that I just wrote above, which is $K^* = \mathbb{conv}\{ \mathbf{zz^T}:\mathbf{z} \succeq 0\}$. Why this extra $\mathbb{conv}$ there, is it because that the set $\{ \mathbf{zz^T}:\mathbf{z} \succeq 0\}$ is not convex and $K^*$ must be closed and convex? I suspect that I did some very cheeky maths here, and I deeply appreciate any guidance.

Comment: In the second equality, you replace $Y$ by $zz^T$ but why are $zz^T$ the only possible $Y$? The set of $zz^T$ is in general just a subset of the dual cone.

Comment: @Rammus my original idea is that since Y needs to satisfy that $\mathbf{\langle \mathbf{X,Y}\rangle}\geq 0$, and $\mathbf{zz^T}$ happens to be the vectors that satisfy that so I wrote the equality?

Comment: You are correct that matrices of the form $zz^T$ satisfy the condition but you have not shown that these are the only possible matrices that satisfy the condition (and indeed they are not). In particular $zz^T$ is rank one but suppose there are two elements $z_1z_1^T$ and $z_2 z_2^T$ where $z_1 \neq \alpha z_2$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $z_1z_1^T + z_2z_2^T$ also satisfies your constraint but is rank $2$ and so does not belong to your set.

Comment: @Rammus so here's I understand it now and please point out any flaws: By declaring $\mathbb{conv}\{ \mathbf{zz^T}:\mathbf{z} \succeq 0\}$ I extend my set to include those linear combinations such as $z_1z_1^T + z_2z_2^T$. But it can't be just any affine set, it must be convex, therefore it needs to be convex so we define a convex hull of this set. And because it is a convex hull of a closed set, it is closed and convex so it satisfies the condition as a dual cone?

Answer (score 1):

One "sanity check" in computing dual cones is that if your new cone is smaller, then your dual cone is bigger. In your case, a copositive cone is bigger than a semidefinite cone, and the dual of a semidefinite cone is the semidefinite cone, so we should expect the dual of the copositive cone to be smaller than the semidefinite cone.

With that in mind, I'm going to make some guesses. Denote $K$ and $K^*$ as the copositive and dual of copositive cone, respectively.

- If $z\geq 0$, then for any $X\in K$, $z^TXz \geq 0$. Then any matrix
  $$
  Y = \sum_{i=1}^m a_ia_i^T
  $$
  where $a_i\geq 0$ is in $K^*$, since $$\mathbf{tr}(XY) = \sum_{i} a_i^TXa_i \geq 0.$$
  Note that the answer doesn't matter if $a_i$ is strictly negative, since the sign cancels out in the product. Therefore
  $$
  K^* \supseteq \{ \sum_{i} a_ia_i^T : a_i \geq 0 \text{ or } a_i \leq 0\}.
  $$
- In fact, this is the entire set for $K^*$. To see this, suppose that $Y = zz^T$ where $z\ngeq 0$ and $z\nleq 0$. Then we can find a copositive $X$ where $z^TXz < 0$. Then $\mathbf{tr}(XY) < 0$.

This is clearly a set smaller than the set of positive semidefinite matrices (which is the proposed set but with no constraints in $a_i$) and thus passes our sanity check.